# Highlighting partial matches using Full-Text-Search in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I'd like to highlight and limit the body of the search results from Postgres's Full-Text-search. My query, taken from Postgres's website, is not retrieving any partial results, and the documentation doesn't indicate whether this is supported.

If not highlight is not available, are there other alternatives I should look into?

```
SELECT *, ts_headline(term, q), rank 
FROM (SELECT id, term, q, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', term), q) as rank
    FROM search_global, plainto_tsquery('doc') q
    WHERE to_tsvector('english', term) @@ q
    ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 6) AS FOO;
```

Comment: What does it mean to you *partial matches*? PostgreSQL full-text-search can look for *words* or also  *prefixes* (which are partial matches). It won't find "mocra" within "democracy". For that, you either need a `LIKE` or a `~` operator.

Comment: Partial matches meaning returning "apples" when I type "appl". I had previously used `@@` to return similar words, but after implementing ts_headline, it stopped working. I took a quick look (it's midnight here) at `LIKE` and `~` -- they aren't listed in FTS's documentation. They seem to be Regex operators, which might not work for search.